# Java Layout Problems

Tags: java, swing

In a project of mine I have been trying to add a JConsonle to a JPanel witch is contained by another JPanel.

The problem is that the JConsole keeps being set 5px from the top of the JPanel.At first I tought it was the container that wasent beeing set up right but after giving it a red background I realised that the console is being set 5px from the top.

I've also tried to use BorderLayout to set it in the NORTH or CENTER of the JPanel but that
dosent work either.

This is my code:

```
public class MonopolyPanel extends JPanel {

  JPanel consoleP = new JPanel();
  JConsole console = new JConsole();

  MonopolyPanel(){

   this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
   console.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(530, 300));  
   consoleP.add(console);
   this.add(consoleP);

  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the `JConsole` control come from?

Comment: It's an external library I found it while reading around stackoverflow http://www.beanshell.org

Comment: I have tryed with all the layout type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console is added to consoleP which has FlowLayout by default, which by default has a vertical and horizontal gap of 5px. Instantiating that with a FlowLayout with zero gaps should do the trick

```
consoleP == new JPanel(new FlowLayout(align, 0, 0));
```

Comment: by the end of the project another 2 panels will exist in the monopolyPanel so it isent unnecesary your solutiion did the trick thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the best and most flexible layout is GridBagLayout.

99% of panels in Swing I make are GridBagLayout, otherwise its impossible to get it all right.

Because with that layout, you can set weights, exact padding and spacing parameters.

The other layoutmanagers are to limited and not very configurable.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at `Border`s?

It's possible you need to set the `JPanel`'s or the `JConsole`'s border to an EmptyBorder, like so:

```
component.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

You might also look for something about insets in the Javadocs.

Comment: no, the "free area" is not set by the border but by the layoutManager - as you could have quickly checked by writing a small sscce to verify your assumption ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah, probably should have :). When I answered this question there was no code sample, and in the past I've found that using EmptyBorder has solved problems with strange insets.